# Virtual box doesn't work

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox, root

Virtual Box doesn't work. When I try to strat any virtual machine I get the next error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows 8.1.

Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_OWNER_NOT_ROOT).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}
```

I had installed the version 4.3.0, and I have completely removed it with Synaptic Package Maneger and have installed the version 4.3.4 but I get the same error.

How to fix it?

Comment: And work with 4.2.16?

Comment: I didn't try, I'm Ubuntu user for 2 months. In windows I have used VMware workstation.

Comment: VirtualBox is in 4.2.16 on Ubuntu. A higher version is unsupported.

Comment: I don't understand: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: open a terminal and write: sudo apt-get install virtualbox  virtualbox-guest-additions-iso

Comment: You can use the Ubuntu software center to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution: `sudo chown root:root /usr /usr/lib /usr/share`

Answer (score 0):

People with the same error code have fixed it with the solution on [this forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=33196).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.